# Complete management of custom attribute in Customer address

Tags: magento2, orders, custom, shipping-address, billing-address

I'm trying to add a custom attribute in Customer Address in Magento 2.3.1 with Wamp (PHP 7.2.25).

I created a custom attribute and additional columns in quote, `sales_order_address` and `quote_address`:

```
    private function createAttribute($code,$desc,$sortOrder)
    {
        $this->eavSetup->addAttribute(
           AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
            $code,
            [
                'label' => $desc,
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'input' => 'text',
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'position' => $sortOrder,
                'sort_order' => $sortOrder,
                'system' => false
            ]
        );

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(
            AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS,
            $code
        );

        $attribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            [   'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
                'customer_address']
        );

        $attribute->save();
    }

    private function addTableColumn($tableName,$fieldCode,$length,$fieldDesc)
    {
        $this->setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $this->setup->getTable($tableName),
            $fieldCode,
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => $length,
                'nullable' => true,
                //'default' => '',
                'comment' => $fieldDesc
            ]
        );
    }
```

I created layout plugin with `/etc/frontend/di.xml --> "Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor"`:

```
    private function buildJsLayout($customAttributeCode,$customAttributeId,$customAttributeDescription,$sortOrder,$scope,$length)
    {
        $this->logger->debug('Hrm_OrderCustomization - LayoutProcessorPlugin - buildJsLayout - ' . $customAttributeCode);

        $this->jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] =
        [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => $scope,
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'additionalClasses' => ' col-mp mp-6',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => $customAttributeId
            ],
            'dataScope' => $scope . '.' . $customAttributeCode,
            'label' => $customAttributeDescription,
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
            'validation' => ['max_text_length' => $length,'min_text_length' => $length],
            'visible' => true,
            'value' =>  '',
            'id' => $customAttributeId
        ];
    }
```

`extension_attribute`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
        <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
            <attribute code="custom_attribute" type="string" />
        </extension_attributes>
    </config>
```

I handled the js:

- create-shipping-address --> create-shipping-address-mixin
- set-shipping-information --> set-shipping-information-mixin
- create-billing-address --> set-billing-address-mixin
- place-order --> set-billing-address-mixin

and i added observe event, /etc/events.xml --> "sales_model_service_quote_submit_before", and AddressManagementPlugins, /etc/di.xml --> "Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement", "Magento\Quote\Model\BillingAddressManagement", "Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\BillingAddressPersister".

I also added the attribute in the admin (and customer account page) like this:

```
     <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit">
        <plugin name="customer-edit-plugin" type="Hrm\OrderCustomization\Plugin\Magento\Customer\AddressEditPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
     </type>

    public function afterGetNameBlockHtml(
        \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $edit,
        $result
    ) {
        $block = $this->layout->createBlock(
            'Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Address\Form\Edit\CustomTemplate',
            'vendor_order_customization'
        );
        return $result . $block->toHtml();
    }
```

`CustomTemplate`:

```
        protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $customWidgetBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Vendor\Module\Block\Customer\Widget\CustomWidget'
        );

        $customWidgetBlock->setAddress($this->address);

        return $customWidgetBlock->toHtml();
    }
```

widget has all get methods (getId, vatLabelDesc ecc...) and getValue():

```
    protected function _construct() 
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('widget/customerAddress.phtml');
    }

    public function getValue()
        {
            $address = $this->getAddress();
            if($address instanceOf AddressInterface)
            {
                    $attr = $address->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')
                                ? $address->getCustomAttribute('custom_attribute')->getValue()
                                : null;

                    return $attr;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and the `phtml`:

```
<div class="field custom_attribute<?php if ($block->isRequired()) echo 'required'; ?>">
    <label class="label" for="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getId()); ?>">
        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()); ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input  type="text" 
                id="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getId()); ?>"
                name="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getName()); ?>"    
                value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getValue()); ?>"
                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()); ?>"
                class="input-text"
            <?php /** @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getParams() ?>
            <?php if ($block->isRequired()) echo ' data-validate="{required:true}"' ?> />
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally i modified the HTML Address Templates in Admin Store --> configuration --> CustomerCustomization, adding:

```
{{depend custom_attribute}}Attribute: {{var custom_attribute}}{{/depend}}
```

well... with this code, the field is saved in table sales_order_address and I can see the value in order details, I can change the value from Admin-Customer or Customer-AddressBook and the new value is loaded correctly on the checkout page, but I have 2 problems:

- if I add a new address in checkout page (or I edit an existing one from the checkout), the custom_attribute  value is not saved in CustomerAddress but only in that specific order
- if the customer has not any address, in checkout page the custom_attribute value doesn't exist in quote.shippingAddress.customAttribute (js mixin) and it cannot be saved even in the DB table

Instead trying to add the property `'user_defined' => true` to the attribute I can save the value in sales_order_address from the checkout page, even if it's a new address BUT... in Admin CustomerAddress I can't save any value and I can't see the value in Order details anymore.

Sorry for the length of this Question and I hope I have explained myself well,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved second point (unlogged customer or customer without addresses) using `'user_defined' => false` and overriding "Magento_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address". Before RETURN i added:

```
        if (addressData['custom_attributes'] === undefined && addressData['custom_attribute'] != undefined) {
           addressData['custom_attributes'] = [];
           addressData['custom_attributes']['custom_attribute'] = {'attribute_code': 'custom_attribute',
                                                        'value': 
           addressData['custom_attribute']};
        }
```

but I still can't save the new field in customer address at place order.